# Limit display to groups with greater than X number of records in a date range

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to filter a report based on the number of records returned in a date range.  I.e. Do not display this group if there are fewer than x records in the last month.  I can successfully use the Count() function to filter on the whole database, but I don't know how to get it to consider only the records returned in the date range (which is set via parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are grouping by date, and there are no times in the date, so I'll refer to that field as `{YourTable.YourDate}` from here.

You can add a custom suppression formula to your Group Header, Details and Group Footer as follows:

```
Count ({YourTable.YourDate}, {YourTable.YourDate}) <= 1
```

The `1` is hard-coded, but you can pass a parameter in, and any groups and details with a count less than or equal to the number passed in will be suppressed.

Comment: Aha, "suppression formula" was what I needed, thanks.  It's still not quite there, though.  I am grouping on date, but count doesn't want to accept it as a valid group.  My grouping is:  CustTable.CustID > CustContactTable.contactDate.  When I try calling Count({CustContactTable.contactDate},{CustContactTable.contactDate}), it tells me "There must be a group that matches this field".

Comment: As a cheat, try adding the {CustContactTable.contactDate} field to your detail section, then clicking on it, going to "Insert", and selecting "Summary".  Select "Count" from the summary, and place this on the report also.  From there, go to your suppression formula, and see if the suppression formula sees your new Count field.

Comment: Interesting. The count is not respecting the number of contacts displayed, but the number of contacts that _would_ be displayed without the date range. For example, say a customer has 5 contacts in September. I am displaying the group monthly (group options > "The section will be printed" = for each month).  If I specify 9/15-9/30 as the date range, the report displays only the two contacts in that range, but the summary count is 5. If I display the group daily, then the count is 1 for each contact. The suppression formula does not see the new Count field - it is a formatting formula.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of adding multiple selection formulas to each group section, I believe you can instead use a single Group Selection formula.

Comment: I've tried using a single Group Selection formula, but I can't get the count to respect my date range parameters.  My formula is `{MyTable.ContactDate} in {@Start Date} to {@End Date}`.  If I add `and Count({MyContactTable.ContactDate},{MyTable.CustomerID}) >= 2`, it will only select customers who have had more than two contacts _ever_.  What I want is for it to select customers who have had more than two contacts between `{@Start Date}` and `{@End Date}`